# Why jsx code in external js fie doesn't work with babel cdn?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I am trying to use babel standalone to tansform jsx code, but it doesn't work when use an external file

This is the code that works:

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel" scr="index.js">
  const App = () => {
    return (<div>hello world</div>)
  }
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
```

But when use an external js file, it doesn't work

html

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="index.js" type="text/babel"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
```

index.js

```js
const App = () => {
   return (<div>hello world</div>)
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Answer (score 4):

It works with an external file too. If it does not work for you, it's most likely not related to Babel or React.

My guess is that your browser is simply not able to fetch `index.js`. If you are testing just the HTML file without a server, then the browser may prevent it from loading `index.js` due to security reasons. E.g. this is what Chrome told me when I tried your code exactly:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///home/xxx/yyy/index.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

I then fired up a basic web server and served `index.js` at `http://localhost:8000/index.js`, and voila - it worked just fine.

Check the browser's console to see if you get this or a similar error. Check the network tab to see if `index.js` is fetched properly. Read about Chrome's (or whatever browser you're using) devtools if you're not sure how to do any of this.

If I am right and you then wish to resolve this problem, it's a completely separate issue, search SO for solutions.

Comment: i am using a live-server on vs-code, and have no errors in my console,  it even doesn't work on mozilla developer edition, i don't understand much about security stuff but any way i appreciate you trying to help

Comment: Can you check the network tab and see if `index.js` is successfully fetched there? Note that if you are indeed running a server and serving `index.html` at `localhost:XXXX`, then `index.js` must be accessible at `localhost:XXXX/index.js` (XXXX stands for the port the server is using). You can simply try opening this URL in a new browser tab. If you get the contents of the file, then the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: this is the right answer - external files work just fine.